# PHP/MYSQL select Limit by two Columns

Tags: php, mysql

I wrote a little script for read data from mysql . but i've a little problem ,

this is my code :

```
    <?php
$con=mysql_connect('localhost','user','pass');
mysql_query("set names utf8");
mysql_query("set charset utf8");
mysql_set_charset('utf8');  
mysql_select_db('dbname',$con);
$query="SELECT * FROM profiles where user_id=11";
$select=mysql_query($query);
while($row=mysql_fetch_array($select)){
echo $row['value'].'  '.'';
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

for now , the script read value of column user_id = 11 , I've another column " key " , how can i read data from this row if , user_id = 11 and key = Age ?

can you help me about this issue ?

Thank you

Comment: `and key = 'Age'` or something like that.

Comment: I've been tried this before , but i do not give any answer , blank page :( thank you

Comment: i've tried this on phpmyadmin , I see ERRoR : " #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'key=Age ORDER BY `profiles`.`user_id` ASC LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1 "

Comment: `key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Comment: is there any way for resolve this issue ? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use

```
`key`='Age'
```

KEY is reserved word in mysql

Comment: THank you , so how can i resolve this issue ? i can't change the column name

Comment: I've used this , i still see Error : 1064

Comment: Please post whole query.

Comment: No no , I've wrote profile for example :D Real Code I've tested in phpmyadmin is : SELECT * FROM `haevm_userxtd_profiles` WHERE user_id=853 `key`='BASIC_FATHER'

Comment: Excellent , I've used this on phpmyadmin and it works , but on php script , i did not recived any answer :D BUT BUT , i See this On php myadmin show query box : SELECT * FROM `haevm_userxtd_profiles` WHERE user_id =853 AND `key` = 'BASIC_FATHER' ORDER BY `haevm_userxtd_profiles`.`user_id` ASC LIMIT 0 , 30  and i've used it on php script too :D NOW The problem Has been SOlved :X THank youuu

Answer (score 0):

Change the `echo $row['value']`.  Instead of the word value, use the column name.

Comment: Hello , the value is the column name :D also when i try this without include the key , I see the response without any problem . i just need it to limit by key . age , mob , date and etc ... . for now . it's print all of information saved in all keys . all rows with user_id 11 . i've many rows with this user ID . but all of them have an extra key name .